# how to find zero and negative values in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find  zero and duplicate values in SQL server values. i have a large values in the table i want to get only duplicate values and zero values 
i have a table three columns in SQL server .please find the below for  database sample like below

```
    Name   Expense    Salary 
    Muni   Airfare     500
    kuno   Hotel      -250
    susi   Airfare      0
    Kavi   Lodge       500
```

i want to get details like

```
    Name    Expense    Salary 
    kuno    Hotel      -250
    susi    Airfare      0
```

how to get this details ? please help me  ?

Comment: Since this is related to `sql` You could ask your question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

use a condition `Salary<=0`

```
select * from tablename
where Salary<=0
```

Comment: i want to get negative values also

Comment: @sripriya, u first execute the query and then chk what is return when a condition is less than zero - this means it should return all negative values

Comment: @sripriya This answer will also retrieve negative salaries.